# checkbox highlighting in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gui, keyboard-navigation

I like navigating forms in web browsers with the keyboard, but chrome is making this very difficult. Normally when you hit tab to select the next form item, a dotted rectangle or something like that highlights it, so you know which item you're editing. Chrome isn't doing that consistently in all web sites. Is there a way to force checkbox highlighting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plugin such as [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) to add your own CSS rules to webpages - make one targetting every webpage and make it do something like

```
*:focus{outline:2px solid blue!important;}
```

To force it on the `:focus` element. You're free to style it up however you want. `outline` is the css element that chrome naturally applies, so this will prevent you from doubly styling webpages where it already exists. `!important` makes it override any previous CSS declarations for the `:focus` on elemenents.